# Манипуляция с цветом карты OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, canvas, render, openlayers

Среди примеров *OpenLayers* есть *[Color Manipulation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/color-manipulation.html)*, который показывает как манипулировать цветом растрового слоя.

Как то же самое сделать со всей *картой*?
Т.е. что бы не только растры, но и все выводимое на карту обрабатывалось (кроме *overlay*, это понятно - они над *canvas* карты).

Использовать ***precompose*** кажется не верным, - он для [другого](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-clipping.html).
Как использовать ***postcompose***, и вообще подходит ли он для этого, не ясно.
Вроде бы ***postrender*** нужно использовать, так как вроде на *canvas* все слои отрисованы и можно обработать все полотно, но... как?